# how to parse text from multiple html files locally stored and write to an excel file

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I used `beautifulsoup` to parse - however it displays the text in last html file only instead of all the html files in the folder. 
I get no errors - it only displays one file when I want it to display text from all the files in the folder.
update: added code to write the text to an excel file - displays text for only one file, how to display all text and sort text in order of length(longest to shortest)?

```py
import os
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Desc.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rootdir = os.getcwd()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith(".html"):

            soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filepath), 'lxml')

            for i in soup.find_all('p', class_=False):
                print(i.text)

descCount = 2

worksheet.write('A1', 'Descriptions')

for i in soup.find_all('p', class_=False):
    worksheet.write('A' + str(descCount), i.text)
    print("{}".format(i.text))
    descCount+=1

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should be inside if block.When you use it outside the loop.It is only taking last soup and finding its element.Hope this will help.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rootdir = os.getcwd()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith(".html"):

            soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filepath), 'lxml')

            for i in soup.find_all('p', class_=False):
                 print(i.text)
```

Comment: that helps greatly! works now.
how do I write the text to an excel file and sort the text by order of length (longest to shortest)? @Kunduk